# Uninstalling Intellij-Idea

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I am trying to uninstall the intellij idea ultimate edition, but when I execute `sudo pacman -Q` no package with that name shows up. Do I have to manually uninstall this application?

Comment: How have you installed Intelij?

Comment: I followed the instructions on their site and downloaded a .tar file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have "installed" it as they told on their site, i.e. 
[image]

no package manager (such as `pacman`, `apt` or `yum`) will be able to notice this "installation". The only way to uninstall this program is to delete the files which appeared after you extracted downloaded `tar.gz` file.

Package managers were invented and created to easily manage with your installed programs. Installing software "manually" should be your last option. You are lucky enough to have access to [ArchLinux user repository](https://aur.archlinux.org/). It has a lot "scripts" to build a package for `pacman`. Look for a package there in case you need something which is not in standard ArchLinux package base. Just be careful, since packages form AUR are under less strict control than the standard repository and might do something unexpected.